# Perl CGI redirect with URI.pm

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi, uri

I have a Perl script which in some cases needs to do a redirect to another one and send all the query parameters along.  The query parameters can contain a lot of data and I do not want to construct and append a messy looking POST string.  Based on some research I have come up with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use URI;

my $query = CGI->new();
my %lots_of_data = $query->Vars;

my $uri = URI->new('http://whatever.com/new_script.pl');
$uri->query_form(\%lots_of_data);

print $query->redirect(-location => $uri);
```

Questions:

1. Will that work?
2. Do I need to use the -nph or -status params for the redirect?
3. How does new_script.pl populate its own CGI query object with the data sent to it, or does the data magically just end up in the query object?

Many thanks!

Comment: No, a redirect won't work. Do you control both scripts?

Comment: I meant you can't redirect without creating the "messy looking" URL you said you didn't want (which is what the code you posted does).

Comment: Thank-you.  I will probably need to serialize the data, yuck.

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer to my question, though. Do you control both scripts?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had posted my reply.  Yes, I control both scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control both scripts, you can use a session. A session is any system where the server stores client-specific information locally to be accessed when servicing later requests by the same client. In order to determine that two requests come from the same client, the server provides the client with an identifier the client is to provide the server in future requests. Cookies are normally used to transmit the identifier, but a single "form" parameter would also do.

For example, if both scripts have access to the same database, you could store the parameters in the database along with an id<sup>[1]</sup> which you'd pass from one script to the other either via a cookie (if the two scripts are on the same domain) or via a parameter

```
new_script.pl?sid=?????
```

I'll let you research the implementation details. [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aSession) might be useful.

---

1. You don't want anyone guessing anyone's session id, so you can't just use an incrementing row id as a session id. You could use the salted hash of one, though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the ideas.  I've decided to serialize the parameters and then redirect to the second script with only the name of the file.

```
my %queryParams = $q->Vars;
my $pid = $$;
my $serializedFile = $tmpDir . "qs". $pid . ".ser";    # /tmp/qs1234.ser

nstore(\%queryParams, $serializedFile);

my $url = $cgiRoot."/cluster/drpSelectGenes.pl?pid=$pid";
print $q->redirect($url);
exit(0);
```

On the receiving end:

```
if ($q->param("pid")) {

    my $serializedFile = $tmpDir . "qs" . $q->param('pid') . ".ser";;
    my %params = %{Storable::retrieve($serializedFile)};

    # move the values into the query object.  (Is there a better way?)
    foreach my $key (keys %params) {
        my $val = $params{$key};
        if ($key eq "fullID") {   # convert null-delimited list into an array
            my @arr = split "\0", $val;     
            $q->param(-name => 'fullID', -values => \@arr);
        } else {
            $q->param(-name => $key, -values => $val);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. to ikegami, this application does use sessions but ties them closely to a database which I'd prefer to steer clear of.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the parameters secret, then use POST, if you got them via a get, then just use URI to plonk the query parameters back onto the URL.

You might not need to use URI, you might just be able to concatenate the new URI woth the $QUERY_STRING environment variable.

If you need to POST, then you shouldn't end up with a lot of messy code. You've already got all the parameters as hash. You should just be able to pass the hash along and have it interpolated into the POST parameters.

If you can use GET, then redirect will work. If you need post, then [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/JESSE/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm), [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/DAGOLDEN/HTTP-Tiny-0.029/lib/HTTP/Tiny.pm), and [LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP.pm) are your friends.

Comment: Thanks, Len.  I do need to use POST but how do I "pass the hash along" via the redirect?

Comment: You'll act as a proxy for the post, rather than a redirect.  use one of the HTTP client libraries, create a POST request, merge your params has with any other params you might need to add for the POST, and then feed to to the request as the params hash.  Check the return value - if it succeeded, then pass the returned body back to the original caller.